# What size icons should go in drawable-[hdpi,mdpi] etc.

Tags: android, android-layout, android-image

I'm new to android coming from the iOS world.

I've placed different image densities of my apps logo in mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi. However, I'm uncertain about what size should other icons be? By other icons I mean, icons in my navigation bar, and table cells.

16x16 icons look extremely small on my emulator. Rather than testing and trying what looks good, I'm wondering if there is a standard around it?

Comment: See my ans here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875158/android-background-image-size-in-pixel/19875228#19875228

Answer (score 2):

Android has documented the size requirement for different components. You can it in the link below :

[ICONOGRAPHY](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html)

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

ldpi should be 36 x 36

mdpi should be 48 x 48

hdpi should be 72 x 72

xhdpi should be 96 x 96

xxhdpi should be 144 x 144

What I do is make an icon of 144 x 144 and change the name to be correct, then use this [tool](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-generic.html#source.type=image&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&size=24&padding=8&color=33b5e5,100&name=reciept) to convert it to all other image sizes. VERY handy! :)

The Android development team has [this](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html) to say

Comment: is that for all icons. not just the app launcher icon?

Comment: The problem is Asset Studio output, which is **VERY POOR QUALITY (72 dpi for all resolutions, regardless of the different screen densities)**. While you should design @ 120 dpi for ldpi up to 480 dpi for xxhdpi.

Answer (score 0):

Design for a specific density (eg: `mdpi` or `hdpi`) and create the icons at whatever size work for your design, then convert their sizes to the other densities.

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html) is pretty explicit about some icons, such as action bar, notifications, etc.

Personally, for in-app and navigation drawer icons, I use icons a little smaller than Action Bar icons.