# How to set height and width for menu icon in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am making one android application in that I am setting menu on actionbar.For that menu contains icon but that icon size is 256*256 but I want that image size should be 64*64 actually I don't have small images so I have to set height and width for that menu item manually please help me.

Comment: Look my ans here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875158/android-background-image-size-in-pixel/19875228#19875228

Answer (score 0):

You can generate different size of ActionBar icon by the [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter) from the icon you have. You can also generate icon for different screen sizes of devices like xxhdpi, xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi as well by it.

[Icon generators](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter) allow you to quickly and easily generate below icons from existing source images, clipart, or text.

```
Launcher icons
Action bar and tab icons
Notification icons
Navigation drawer indicator
Generic icons
Tab icons (pre-Android 3.0)
Menu icons (pre-Android 3.0)
```