# Which image size should be placed in the neutral drawable folder?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, drawable

Which size of an image should be placed in the neutral drawable folder?

I have an icon file in **5 different** versions:

- 24x24 = ldpi
- 32x32 = mdpi
- 48x48 = hdpi
- 64x64 = xhdpi
- 96x96 = xxhdpi

On the other hand I have **6 different** folders:

- /drawable
- /drawable-ldpi
- /drawable-mdpi
- /drawable-hdpi
- /drawable-xhdpi
- /drawable-xxhdpi

5 Files and 6 folders means that either one folder has to stay empty (which one?) or one file has to be used twice?

This is what the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) say:

> If no matching resource is available, the system uses the default
>   resource and scales it up or down as needed to match the current
>   screen size and density
>
> The "default" resources are those that are not tagged with a
>   configuration qualifier. For example, the resources in drawable/ are
>   the default drawable resources. The system assumes that default
>   resources are designed for the baseline screen size and density, which
>   is a normal screen size and a medium density. As such, the system
>   scales default density resources up for high-density screens and down
>   for low-density screens, as appropriate.
>
> However, when the system is looking for a density-specific resource
>   and does not find it in the density-specific directory, it won't
>   always use the default resources. The system may instead use one of
>   the other density-specific resources in order to provide better
>   results when scaling. For example, when looking for a low-density
>   resource and it is not available, the system prefers to scale-down the
>   high-density version of the resource, because the system can easily
>   scale a high-density resource down to low-density by a factor of 0.5,
>   with fewer artifacts, compared to scaling a medium-density resource by
>   a factor of 0.75.

OK, that the mdpi version should be placed in drawable-mdpi, ldpi in drawable-ldpi, etc. is out of question. But which version goes to the neutral folder?

Should I place the xxhdpi files there (scale down if no match is found)? What about the -xxhdpi folder than? Keep it empty or place the files there as well?

Comment: see my ans here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875158/android-background-image-size-in-pixel/19875228#19875228

Comment: @Haresh Thanks, but the linked answer is just a list of different sizes for different elements (background, list, etc.). How does this answer the question which size to place in which folder?

Comment: You can place XML-drawables, which independent of screen size there.

Comment: in your case "/drawable" this folder stay empty.

Comment: Mmmh, if "/drawable" stays empty, how does the system know which file is the default resource? As the docu says the system assumes that the files in "/drawable" are "designed for the baseline screen size and density". Would it not be better to place the mdpi files here and leave the -mdpi folder empty?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default `/drawable` folder expects `mdpi images`. And mostly used in 2 cases:

> 1. To have non-density dependent images. **eg:** selectors, which indirectly link to images from density named folders again.
> 2. To have all the images in only this folder and ignore all the other drawable folders. In which case the images will be scaled depending on
>      the screen density.

**For your case:**

> You can keep only xml files like selectors in the default `/drawable`
>   folder and other images in their respective folders