# How android scales drawables? If I have xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi but don't have ldpi?

Tags: android, android-layout

How android scales drawables?
In project I have xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi but I don't have ldpi.
What will happen if I run app on phone with ldpi screen?

I know that drawables will be scaled down automatically. But which drawables will be taken? From mdpi?

Comment: Look at my ans here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875158/android-background-image-size-in-pixel/19875228#19875228

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the [official android iconography](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html) site. If you run into an android phone with ldpi screen then the system will effectively downscale your assets from hdpi. Hdpi was choosen because its resolution is twice of ldpi. So maybe the downscaling would be simpler(perhaps faster) if taken from hdpi.