# How to set up my photoshop for Android UI design?

Tags: android, user-interface, photoshop

How to set up my Photoshop for Android UI design ? I have several dimension e.g

- 540 x 960
- 960 x 540
- 480 x 800
- 800 x 480
- 1024 x 600
- 600 x 1024
- 1024 x 800
- 800 x 1024
- 1280 x 800
- 800 x 1280

So how could I set up Photoshop ? Or does i set up through mdpi, Ldpi, Hdpi? 
What should be resolution for this dimension?

Comment: this question is asked about million times, check this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875158/android-background-image-size-in-pixel/19875343#19875343

Comment: developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html, see the `Set up a working space that organizes files by density` section. That's how I'm working at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

To create alternative drawable bitmap for different densities, You Should follow the scaling ratio 3:4:6:8 Between the oven generalized densities. For example, if You Have a drawable bitmap that's 48x48 pixels for medium-density screen (the size for a launcher icon), all the different sizes Should Be:

```
      36x36 for low-density (LDPI)

      48x48 for medium-density (MDPI)

      72x72 for high-density (HDPI)

      96x96 for extra high-density (XHDPI)

      144x144 for extra extra high-density (XXHDPI)
```

This is for Splash screen image size

- xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
- large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
- normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
- small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

More information on multiple screens [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a Hi-res image and use a tool to get it for differents resolutions.

Like this one:

http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html