# Multiple screen support for my app?

Tags: android, optimization, drawable, screen-size

I am quite confused whether I have to deal with my device, which I'm currently testing my app on, as a medium or large density device. The device is Samsung Galaxy S3 mini with 480 x 800 pixels, 4.0 inches display according to the device specifications provided by Samsung.

I am planning to optimize my drawables such that a wide range of screen sizes and densities are supported. Since S3 mini is my testing device, which launcher icon is actually the one used in it? is it the one under drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi or drawable-xhdpi?

Comment: Check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875158/android-background-image-size-in-pixel/19875228#19875228

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. Does my testing phone use drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi or drawable-xhdpi?

Comment: it depend on your testing device screen resolution.

Comment: @Haresh thank you, I have answered my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
switch (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi) {
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
         // write your code here.
         break;
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
         // write your code here.
         break;
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
         // write your code here.
         break;
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
         // write your code here.
         break;
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
         // write your code here.
         break;
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV:
         // write your code here.
         break;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked my device's used drawable by detecting the width of the launcher icon as follows:

```
BitmapDrawable bd=(BitmapDrawable) this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
Log.i("moayad", ""+ bd.getBitmap().getWidth());
```

The reported width is 72 which is the width of the icon placed in the drawable-hdpi folder. Hence, my phone is categorized under the high density folder.