# Create icons for multiple versions of drawable in Android

Tags: java, android

My problem is in Eclipse - Android SDK

I have collected a set of icon for my application. However, these icons are really big, and I don't know how to reduce the size as well as quality(for smaller size in hard disk).

Recently, I have tried to use PAINT but I fail.

Comment: I've only used Eclipse/ADT once, a while ago, but isn't there an option to specify an app icon when creating a project, and the different sizings are done for you? Also, if you mean icons/images other than the app icon, you're essentially asking us to recommend an image editor, which is off-topic for this site.

Comment: Check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875158/android-background-image-size-in-pixel/19875228#19875228

Answer (score 0):

You could try uploading the large icons and [this](http://goo.gl/2Oc9vv) will shrink them down to multiple sizes for the different screen variants on Android while also keeping the size at a minimum. It is pretty self explanatory from there. You download the .zip file and copy the contents of each folder inside to your project.

If your asking how to actually design the icon, Photoshop or Gimp are good for advanced editing but that is considered an off-topic question on this forum.