# Android UI (Layouts + Resources) for different screen sizes and different densties

Tags: android-layout, android

First of all, I have seen all the available answers on SO but could not get **exactly** what I wanted to ask, therefore I am writing this question here, it might help others too.

**What I know**

To support multiple densties we should provide different resources (images) in drawable folders by considering the following,

```
ldpi    :  0.75x
mdpi    :  1x
hdpi    :  1.5x
xhdpi   :  2x
xxhdpi  :  3x
xxxhdpi :  4x
```

For example, if we have an image of size 100X100 px in mdpi then, size of icons for other densties will be,

```
ldpi    :   75X75 px
mdpi    :   100X100 px
hdpi    :   150X150 px
xhdpi   :   200X200 px
xxhdpi  :   300X300 px
xxxhdpi :   400X400 px
```

**My Questions:**

1. As there can be multiple screen resolutions in one density then while designing the icons for suppose mdpi which resolution should be considered? Suppose the designer is creating the Screen in Photoshop and then will give cut outs of the icons, then which screen resolution from mdpi should be considered?
2. Will same image be shown on all the screen resolutions having same density. For example, like we have resolution from 480X600 to 1920X1200 in hdpi, then will same image be shown on these two resolutions? Will it not look small in 1920X1200 resolution rather than 480X600?
3. What if we want to design a custom background image that should fit properly to all screen sizes? What should be the approach for the same? Suppose we want to design a background image for hdpi, then for which resolution should we design it? (480X600 or 1920X1200). I think it will not fit properly on all screen sizes.
4. What should be a better approach to make the design to be resolution independent?
5. What designers here do is, select a resolution, design the whole app screen in that resolution, cut out/slice the psd to get icons. But this way the design becomes resolution dependent, it doesn't work good on other screens with other resolutions. What should be the best way to achieve screen resolution independent.

Any body knows good solutions to create resolution independent UI for Android?

Thanks.

Comment: Check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875158/android-background-image-size-in-pixel/19875228#19875228

Comment: @Haresh Can you please elaborate all things in the question and help me clear my doubts? I think I am missing something to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my experience what I learned is,

1. Phones

   ```
   hdpi - 480 x 800
   xhdpi - 768 x 1280
   xxhdpi - 1080 x 1920
   xxxhdpi - 1440 x 2560
   ```

   Tables
       large-mdpi - 600 x 1024
       xlarge-mdpi - 800 x 1280
2. For tablets design different cutouts.
3. Get it created for all the resolutions you want to support.
4. Getting cutouts for most famous resolution for each category.
5. Get cutouts for one resolution from each category and different cutout images for tablets.

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm giving answer of your first 3 questions. See below:

1. Designing icons for mdpi, you should consider 320x480 mdpi resolution as a base standard. According to this, you can resize images for different screen resolutions.
2. If you consider mdpi as your UI baseline, then you need to resize images as per        0.75x : 1x  :  1.5x :  2x :  3x :  4x this scenario/std.
3. Designing background image, you need 480x800 hdpi image size. Because most of hdpi devices lie on 480x800 this size.

Comment: i don't think 320*480 is suitable resolution for icons.see Supporting Multiple screens in developer.android.com

Comment: Actually most of the mdpi devices fall in this category. So considering this resolution for mdpi as a baseline is completely fine approach as per my knowledge.

Comment: I know this thing, which you mentioned in Point 2. But my question is, suppose we create an image as per 320X480 mdpi resolution, then if we want to get image for 1280x768 mdpi resolution, then what? Do we need to create images for each resolution separately? Or the same image designed for 320X480 mdpi will be shown for 1280X768 resolution? As both are mdpi?

Comment: You can use same image for 1280x768 mdpi resolution device. But it will look stretched on that device. So best way create images for different screen resolution.

Comment: As there are more than 12 resolutions, so you want to say that we should create so many images each for one resolution? And where do you think are going to put them? Say if there are 4 resolutions for mdpi only and we create 4 different images, then where should we put them? All cannot be placed with same name in the same folder.

Comment: You need to google for mapping different resolution images in different drawable. Actually your above comment is not part of this question else you need to edit your question.