# Android set a specific layout for a specific device

Tags: android

I'm currently developing an app that as usual has to run on multiple devices but there is one more special than the others. An Acer DA241HL which is a 24" "Tablet" with a 1920x1080px resolution that should be wall mounted somewhere.

Is there a good way to identify this screen. Right now it reacts to the values-sw600dp folder. But what ever changes I make for this enormous tablet shouldn't affect normal tablet which would happen if I change stuff in that folder.

The following code:

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float density  = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    float dpHeight = metrics.heightPixels / density;
    float dpWidth  = metrics.widthPixels / density;
    Log.e("screen", "******************************************************");
    Log.w("screen", "d " + density + " y" + dpHeight + " x" + dpWidth + " deviceType:" + getResources().getString(R.string.device_type));
    Log.e("screen", "******************************************************");
```

Print the following:

```
******************************************************
d 1.0 y1032.0 x1920.0 deviceType:5
******************************************************
```

But I dont see how I can make that useful. 
The other way I thought about is to get the model number of the device but that creates new problem if they decide to get a similar device but not the same.

Suggestions?

Comment: Check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875158/android-background-image-size-in-pixel/19875228#19875228

Comment: @Haresh thanks but that doesn't really solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a good way to identify this screen

Use something like `-swNNNdp`, for a suitably high value of `NNN`.

> Right now it reacts to the values-sw600dp folder

Well, sure, but that screen is far larger than 600dp in its smallest width.

> But what ever changes I make for this enormous tablet shouldn't affect normal tablet which would happen if I change stuff in that folder.

Then add a `res/values-sw1000dp/` directory, for resources to use for screens with 1000dp in the smallest width, which will include your Acer but will not include more normal-sized tablets.

Comment: thanks for your answer! But as long as I have strings.xml in that folder (values-sw1000db) I get a crash with no logcat output. dimens.xml works. Any suggestions?

Comment: @just_user: "I get a crash with no logcat output" -- I find that difficult to believe. If you are crashing, you should be getting a stack trace in LogCat. I'm also not quite clear why your strings would be changing in this case. Without a stack trace or something more to go on, I don't really have any idea what may be going wrong.

Comment: no idea why I dont get a stacktrace in the LogCat for that. Other crashes are all reported. But if I rename strings.xml in that folder to xstrings.xml it works. I keep one string there to identify the device type, phone, tablet and now huge-tablet to load content of menus dynamically. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @just_user: "But if I rename strings.xml in that folder to xstrings.xml it works" -- since the filename in `values` resource directories does not matter, this is very strange.

Comment: Indeed. What makes it stranger is strings.xml in "values-sw600dp" has no troubles at all.