# what's background image size for TabPageIndicator of ViewPagerIndicator

Tags: android, android-styles, viewpagerindicator

I'm using Android-ViewPagerIndicator in my project and I'm trying to customize TabPageIndicator style. I found I need to create my indicator background drawable like in [default source](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/tree/master/library/res/drawable-hdpi), but I don't know the actual size of the image.

Anyone can help me? Thanks.

Comment: Check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875158/android-background-image-size-in-pixel/19875228#19875228

Comment: @Haresh the second answer seemed to make sense, I'll try it, thanks