# android app launcher icon

Tags: android, icons, resolution

I'm trying to put the finishing touches on my app design. The launcher icon I have been using is properly scaled for mdpi,hdpi,x,xx but still seems to appear of lower resolution. I've tried a few other things, deleting all lower resolution versions and using a ridiculously oversized version. The logo I'm sizing down is very high resolution to start with. I am doing this all in photoshop. I'm checking the icon appearance using my phone and not an emulator and just to be certain, I've been deleting the app so a new icon is loaded each time.

Comment: You are down scaling and the resolution is low?

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875158/android-background-image-size-in-pixel/19875228#19875228

Comment: @Haresh that is simply a list of the pixel dimensions, I have that part down.

Comment: @PrivatMamtora yep. that is the part that is really messing with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use other icons and see what makes it happened.
No need to use a very high resolution.

Comment: this solved it. more specifically, it directed me to the problem which  was there was a file higher up containing launcher icon res with the same name and an old image. the app was using those and not my replacements. oops.

Answer (score 1):

Try to load the icon at the time when you are creating new app as shown in the screen shot. maybe you got help from this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to [ANDROID ASSET STUDIO](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0&foreColor=33b5e5%2C0&crop=0&backgroundShape=bevel&backColor=ffffff%2C100)

Browse your image and it will generate all the scaled resolution images, then try using the high resolution image. Maybe that would work.

Comment: Gave that a try, seemed like a good thought. The image the was created looked a bit better in AS but looked no different once installed