# How to optimize a image with a large resolution of 1920x1080, in order to make it as a background?

Tags: android, image, background-image, android-drawable

I have a Tabhost in my app which have 5 tabs in it. I set a background image on my tabhost by putting `android:background = "@drawable/background"` in my xml file, but unfortunately the whole ui becomes laggy. How can I optimize the image in order to eliminate the lag in my UI? Please help me with this one.

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background = "@drawable/background">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FCAFA6"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height= "52dp"
                android:background="@drawable/header" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tabTitle"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Home"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </FrameLayout>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0" >
        </TabWidget>
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875158/android-background-image-size-in-pixel/19875228#19875228

Comment: Why you delete your connectToServer with custom interface question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make various device size background and put on respective folder for more check this :[Android background image size in pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875158/android-background-image-size-in-pixel/19875228#19875228)