# How to make android layout(UI) suitable for both hdpi and xxhdpi

Tags: android, android-layout

In my layout all content(text and images) load through server.when application run on both hdpi and xxhdpi bottom layout components are not showing.

HDPI Screenshot

[image: HDPI]

XXHDPI Screenshot

[image: xxhdpi]

Is there any way to make layout to suitable for all device category?

bellow is my layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:textAlignment="gravity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="#ffebd5ca"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:background="#ffebd5ca"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/titlelogo" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffebd5ca"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >



            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            </FrameLayout>

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="#ffebd5ca"
                android:showDividers="none"
                android:tabStripEnabled="true"
                android:tabStripLeft="@drawable/btnline2"
                android:tabStripRight="@drawable/btnline2"
                android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
                android:gravity="bottom" >



            </TabWidget>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:background="#ffebd5ca"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ff5a3e30" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="8dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/logo_border"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/mLogoAdView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtCompany"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="SAMSUNG PVT LTD."
                    android:textColor="@color/tabhost_text_select"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtAddressLine1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="No 124, Main Street, Colombo 07"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="#ffd3bdb2"
                    android:textSize="10dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtTelephone"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="12dp"
                    android:text="T.P       :      011-2345678"
                    android:textColor="@color/tabhost_text_select"
                    android:textSize="10dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtMobile"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Mobile :      011-2345678"
                    android:textColor="@color/tabhost_text_select"
                    android:textSize="10dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875158/android-background-image-size-in-pixel/19875228#19875228

Comment: @HareshChhelana In my layout all component load by server.Is there any way to balance content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**7-inch tab**

Create the folder name -`values-sw600dp`(under res folder)

1.under values-sw600dp->create dimen.xml

**10-inch tab**

Create the folder name -`values-sw720dp`(under res folder)

1.under values-sw720dp->create dimen.xml

Using dp values in 2:3:4:6:8 scaling ratio between the five primary densities (medium, high, x-high, xx-high, and xxx-high respectively);

values->dimens.xml

```
<dimen name="five_dp">5dp</dimen>
```

values-sw600dp->dimens.xml

```
<dimen name="five_dp">10dp</dimen>
```

values-sw600dp->dimens.xml

```
<dimen name="five_dp">15dp</dimen>
```