# Android image squashed

Tags: android, image, android-image, android-background

I have an image with a resolution of 1024x1024 pixels.

[image: original image]

But, when I try to use this image in my Android app (background activity) it is squashed.

[image: squashed image]

Can anyone tell me how to avoid this?

Now this issue has been fixed by using following code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/image" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

But this solution can not use for following code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:background="@drawable/frontscreenbg"/>

    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollviewParentLoginContainer"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:wheel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutLoginContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="24dp"
            android:paddingRight="24dp">
```

Please help me.

Comment: You can achieve this by putting an `ImageView` in the background with `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`

Comment: what is want exactly want

Comment: @zkminusck I am bot using ImageView, I am trying to set the background of Relaytive Layout.

Comment: @Albert,You have make various images for multiple device screen support please check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875158/android-background-image-size-in-pixel/19875228#19875228

Comment: Dont we have any other option?

Answer (score 3):

Don't set the image as the background of your root layout. Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/your_background_image"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
      ...
     /* Your other UI elements */
      ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can't set scale type in a `RelativeLayout`

Comment: I am trying to set the background image of my _RelativeLayout_. Can you suggest me how to do this for _RelativeLayout_.

Comment: Nope, RelativeLayout doesn't have scaleType attribute.

Comment: Actually I wanted to set background of the whole layout, that is why I am trying to set background image of my RelativeLayout.

Comment: I understand, that's why you have to add "match_parent" value as your ImageView width and hegiht, so it will be the background of your whole layout. See my code snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the Scale Type option of your ImageView to CENTER_CROP (see here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

you can do it programmatically using the `setScaleType()` method of ImageView or adding it to your xml layout using `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`

**EDIT:**
If you want to add the background directly to your layout, you have to create a custom drawable object inside the /res/drawable directory. Try to use something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/background_image"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

Comment: I tried _android:scaleType="centerCrop"_ in my xml file. Ithink because I am not using ImageView, I am trying to set background of _RelativeLayout_.

Answer (score 0):

Just use following code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/image" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This should resolve your issue.